# jQuery MagicSuggest disable selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I've looked through the MagicSuggest documentation http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html but I've been unable to find a solution to the following:

I would like to disable specific selection options in the drop-down pane while still showing them. In other words: I'd like to display all the selection options but only allow some to be selected, the others would be greyed out or something along those lines.

Is there an elegant way to do this or am I going to have to come up with a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just added in 2.1.0 release. Look at the docs for the property `disabledField` and you'll find what you were looking for.